# Java Regex for protecting xSS

Tags: java, regex

I want to use java Regex to check whether there is `<script/>` in my url. I want to match if characters of url occur in  `['"&<>\/]` , But for java ,the regex is little different, I do not know how to write correct regex to match. Can someone can help me?

Comment: you are looking for this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: You can use www.txt2re.com to create Java regex.

Comment: **This will not be secure!** There are several ways to defeat the security you're describing (for example, `%3Cscript%3E`). Use a proper URL sanitizing library, or better yet, avoid pasting querystring parameters into your page.

Answer (score 2):

Never do Html Encoding/Decoding/Validation yourself. If you ever encounter code that is manually validating html, xml etc... it is a bug. Always use a library that is well used and peer reviewed for these sorts of tasks. Don't be a cowboy coder and think you can do it well; it is much harder to get right than you might think. The [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation) site has everything you need to know about how to do this in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

How are you displaying the query string parameter? If you are doing this in a JSP file you can simply use the `<c:out>` tag to escape it:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:out value="${param.myUnsafeParam}" />
```